# How to call constructor and variables from another class?

Tags: class, constructor, private-members

I have a main class:

```
class Sportist{
    private:
        string ime;
        int godina_na_ragjanje;
        int godisna_zarabotuvacka_EUR;
    public:
        Sportist(string i, int g_n_r, int g_z_EUR){
            ime = i;
            godina_na_ragjanje = g_n_r;
            godisna_zarabotuvacka_EUR = g_z_EUR;
        }
};
```

And now I have a new class like this:

```
class Fudbaler:public Sportist{
    private:
        int broj_na_odigrani_natprevari;
        int danocna_stapka;
    public:
        Fudbaler(string ime, int godina, int zarabotuvacka, int b, int d){
            :Sportist(ime, godina, zarabotuvacka)
            broj_na_odigrani_natprevari = b;
            danocna_stapka = d;
        }
        float danok(){
            return godisna_zarabotuvacka_EUR * danocna_stapka;
        }
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, Fudbaler F){
            return os << "Ime: " << ime << endl
                      << "Godina na raganje: " << godina_na_ragjanje << endl
                      << "Godisna zarabotuvacka(EUR): " << godisna_zarabotuvacka_EUR << endl
                      << "Danok sto treba da plati: " << danok();
        }
};
```

I want to call the constructor from the first class in the second class, but I get errors that I haven't provided arguments which I do.. and also, I want to know how to access the private elements from the first class in the second, because it's taken as 'public', so how can I use them in my functions, like danok().

Errors while calling the constructor:

no matching function for call to 'Sportist::Sportist()'

candidates are:

Sportist::Sportist(std::string, int, int)

candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided

Error while calling variables using public method:

'int Sportist::godisna_zarabotuvacka_EUR' is private

Comment: Post your attempt at calling the constructor and the verbatim error msg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not initialize `Sportist` before you enter your `Fudbaler` constructor function body. Therefore the Compiler tries to use a default constructur of `Sportist` which does not exists.
You Need to initialize `Sportist` before entering the `Fudbaler` constructor body.

Initializers are appended after the closing parenthesis before the function body in curly brackets:

```
    Fudbaler(string ime, int godina, int zarabotuvacka, int b, int d)
       : Sportist(ime, godina, zarabotuvacka), 
        broj_na_odigrani_natprevari(b), 
        danocna_stapka(d)
    {
    }
```

Private variables are private and cannot be accessed in child classes.
If you want to Access the `Sportist` members in `Fudbaler` member function you need to declare them `protected` (only accessible in this class and child classes) or `public` (generally accessible).

Comment: Thanks, it fixed one of the problems. What about private variables from the class, can I access them the normal way, since I used the 'public' word?

Comment: `ime`, `godina_na_ragjanje` and `godisna_zarabotuvacka_EUR` are private in `Sportist`. So only `Sportist` members or friends cann acccess them.

Comment: I understand. I have to declare them as protected to be able to use them. Thanks a lot!